# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: queryKey [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

Tags: java, spring, aop

My aspect is:

```
@Aspect
@Service
public class MyAspect {

    @AfterReturning(value="(execution(* find(..)) )" +
            "&& target(com.erp.core.service.IBaseApplicationService) " +
            "&& args(queryKey,object,..)")
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("find method called");
    }


}
```

The type name which AOP doesn't find is in:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List find(String queryKey, Object[] object) {
    return baseRepository.find(queryKey, object);
}
```

The find is base method so whenever i open a page it will be called.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: queryKey [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:301)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:195)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:181)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:162)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:200)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:254)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:286)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
```

It shows that no match for the type name queryKey

Comment: Its hard to tell what the issue is with the details you provided. I assume the error happens on the line baseRepository.find(..). can you include the stacktrace ?

Comment: @Srini i added the stack trace

Comment: check the answer below and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use args in the binding form, you need to include the parameters to be bound in your method advice.
    Note the method declaration below
**EDIT**

```
@AfterReturning(value="(execution(* find(..)) )" +
            "&& target(com.erp.core.service.IBaseApplicationService) " +
            "&& args(queryKey,object,..)",returning="returnList")
    public void **print(String queryKey, Object[] object,List returnList)**
    {
        System.out.println("find method called");
    }
```

Comment: How can i print the size of that List in my @Aspect ?